# Background image on Slick Slider slide not expanding to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am trying to add a slider to an existing page that has a left and right side. The left side has a background image, some text and a clear fix that expands the image to the height of the right side.

When I use Slick Slider and make the left side element a slide, the clear fix no longer works and the height is dictated by the content of the left element.

Here are 2 jsfiddles that demonstrate the problem:
Without slider: http://jsfiddle.net/robmccart/15wrct6g/
With slider: http://jsfiddle.net/robmccart/yj9nerh1/

Here's the code with slider:

```
<div class="parent">
    <section class="right-side"></section>

    <section class="slider left-side">
        <div class="row" style="background-image: url(http://cpaws.org/engaging-networks/images_donation/Donation-pg-Peel-Watershed.jpg);">slide1</div>
        <div class="row" style="background-image: url(http://cpaws.org/engaging-networks/images_donation/Donation-pg-Peel-Watershed.jpg);">slide2</div>
        <div class="row" style="background-image: url(http://cpaws.org/engaging-networks/images_donation/Donation-pg-Peel-Watershed.jpg);">slide3</div>

    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;
.parent {
    background: #336633;
}
.right-side {
  float: right;
  height: 700px;
}
.left-side {
    padding-right: 450px;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the clear fix properly, but it looks like the code injected by Slick Slider is breaking something.

Thanks

Comment: From the question, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I'm trying to get the height of the left side equal to the height of the right side. The first jsfiddle shows an example where the height of the right side is 700px. The background image of the left side covers to a height of 700px. When I add the slider, the height of the left side is based on the content of the left side.